# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined while using jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have an issue with using JQgrid wiith rails. In the following code i get 3 errors. I am not even able to hit the url.

The errors are

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined -> grid.locale-en.js
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined -> jquery.jqgrid.min.js
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined -> at '$(function () {'

from the following code.

Any help would be appreciated. I think i have missed something small here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/assets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/assets/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script type="/assets/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="/assets/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'/users/jq', 
       datatype: "json", 
      colNames:['ID','NAME','DISPLAY NAME'], 
      colModel:[{name:'id', index:'id',resizable:false,width:35},
                {name:'USERNAME'  , index:'USERNAME',edittype:'text',editable:true},
                {name:'FIRST_NAME', index:'FIRST_NAME',edittype:'text',editable:true},
                {name:'LAST_NAME' , index:'LAST_NAME',edittype:'text',editable:true}
               ], 
        mtype: "GET",
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 5,
        rownumbers: true,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        height: 'auto',
        width: '500',
        loadonce: true,
        caption: "My first grid"
    }); 
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that jQuery is really included on the page? You use

```html
<script type="/assets/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="/assets/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
```

instead of

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
```

(the value of `type` attribute is definitively wrong for jQuery and jQuery UI).

Comment: thanks @oleg the first 2 issues are gone but the third i.e. $ is undefined is still there

Comment: @sethi: $ is undefined only if the path `"js/jquery-1.8.3.js"` is wrong. Moreover you have to add one more element in `colNames`, for example append it with `'LAST_NAME'`. [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sethi.htm) has your code, but just loads all JavaScript libraries from internet. It display the grid, without the data of cause. Additionally I recommend you to add `gridview: true, autoencode: true` to the options which you use.